# Splitting a simple specific path on windows and linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

### Problem:

I'm having different behavior for Windows and Linux in the following case.

```
import os
path = '..\\file.hdf'
norm_path = os.path.normpath(path)
splitted_path = os.path.split(norm_path)
print(splitted_path)
```

### Behavior

On Windows I get `('', 'file.hdf')`

On Linux I get `('', '..\\file.hdf')`

### Question

**Is there a better/specific way to use the os.path for this?**

### Workaround

Ok, it's easily fixed with `norm_path.split('\\')`, but that's not dynamic at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, paths are separated with a forward slash. If you want a platform-independent approach, I suggest using `os.sep` instead of backslash:

```
import os
path = '..' + os.sep + 'file.hdf'
norm_path = os.path.normpath(path)
split_path = os.path.split(norm_path)
print(split_path)
```

Comment: if it's more than two members to concatenate you might  write something like 
`os.sep.join("..", "data", "file.hdf")`

Answer (score 1):

In Linux `\` is NOT a path separator. Therefore, your `..\\file.hdf` means "a file named `file.hdf` in the parent directory of the current directory" on Windows, but simply "a file named `..\file.hdf` in current directory" on Linux. I suggest using `pathlib` module instead of `os.path`:

```
import pathlib
norm_path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath('..\\file.hdf')
split_path = list(norm_path.parts)
# ['..', 'file.hdf'] both on Linux and Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `\\` with `/`

Windows can handle `/` as path separator.

Linux can't handle `\\`

So use `/` for any code you want to be able to be running on Linux and Windows

Or do it the really clean way by using `os.sep` as @snibbets suggests.

In that case I'd use `os.sep.join('..', 'file.hdf'`)